# Why no drug dependant aliens?

Tags: aliens

I've wanted to ask you this.

While the dynamic of using money and credits is a well defined one, in our society, as well as it will probably be in any alien society that is advanced and liberal enough, and so is the dynamic of acquiring and using guns and ammo, why is the dynamic of using drugs medicinally and recreationaly, as well as drug dependency rarely used in fiction? Also, the concept of fraud is rarely expanded, but that is another topic...

Comment: Fraud is complicated and boring. Drug use is pretty common in all senses.

Comment: We answer questions about the rules of your world. Not questions about other fictional worlds.

Comment: I don't see a worldbuilding question? And in the movie District 9 this is very much the case. Drugs, arms dealing, poverty, prostitution.... they made the aliens an allegory for black people in some American city. They even get forcibly moved to a different district.

Comment: @Trioxidane, they made the aliens an allegory for black people in apartheid South Africa. It was very much a movie for the local market.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Jem'Hadar in Star Trek, one of the major antagonist races of *Star Trek: Deep Space 9* are as an entire race addicted to a drug created by the founders to control them.

And if I am not mistaking the Reimagined Battlestar Galatica handled drug abuse during their Black Market episode (an highly underrated episode if you ask me)

So it's not unheard of but the reason it is rare is probably due to censorship. The inclusion of drugs are often a reason why shows get a higher rating which is what you preferably (especially before the Deadpool era) don't want. Also most Sci-Fi is either highly optimistic like Star-Trek where drugs are out of place or highly depressing where something more relatable like alcohol does the job of filling the addiction role.

Answer (score 0):

Probably off topics, but drugs (namely a dependency from ginger terpenes) is a major plot point in the Invasion/Colonization cycle by Harry Turtledove. Maple syrup plays a similar role in John Ringo's Troy series. *Tofacco* (i.e., tobacco) has a central role in Hal Clement's *Iceworld*.
Star's Tears (if I back-translate it correctly) are the real reason there *is* a Dameii Station in James Tiptree Jr.'s *Brightness Falls from the Air*.

Less seriously, in Bonvi and Guccini's *Stories from Deep Space* there is a story, I believe inspired by Sheckley, where aliens get high on Sanagola Cough Drops.